# an Exception has occurred _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value), how can i git rid of it?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I don't know what happened. I mean, I tried to replace the ! within ?, but it shows Errors:
[image]

Comment: When you do `!` you promise the compiler that the value will never be `null` in this situation and the program should crash if the value is going to be `null` at runtime. So the error tells you that you broke the promise about this value never being `null`.

Comment: Share your code to get better answer avoid adding code image.